# Anonymous variable usage in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, reflection

Is it possible (and how) to use declared variables in a method **anonymously** ? Without using their names in the code per se. I **must** declare them with a name (for readability + debugging). But I would like to use them without.

I wished it would be possible like list all method names of a class via reflection.

---

**Example:**

```
private static void TestVars()
{
    string dsjkfd4378957439898 = "hello world";
    string hgf43789 = "hello world2";
    string ntgdklf4589 = "hello world3";
    // more strings

    // print names of ALL string variables above (and their values)
    // like this but without knowing the names of the string variables
    Console.WriteLine("dsjkfd4378957439898" + " = " + dsjkfd4378957439898);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please detail your question. it is hard to understand what you asking.

Comment: Why don't you use just a set of elements of the desired type or object if you will use different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not. Variables must have names.

I'm going to hazard a guess and say What you probably want is a proper data structure such as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (if you want names) or a `List<T>` (if you don't want names). A proper debugger will be able to inspect data structures.

The reason you can't list variables is that things like variable names aren't stored in the resulting bytecode - all that's left is possibly an index. Additionally some variables might get optimized away and disappear completely in a non-debug build. Variable names and locations will be stored in the debugging information for debug builds, but there's no standard way to access that, as it's information that should be used by debuggers only and not your own logic.

Comment: I didn't ask two questions. I know how to list and invoke methods of classes. I made an example of how I would like to handle variables.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I guess I misread. I added an explanation as to why you can't list variables.